# Questions about using Futures and Completers

Tags: dart, dart-async

Hey have I read all I can find about futures, but I would like some more advice on proper usage.

I am writing an API library, that bridges the gap between HTTP Requests and the app. So I use the future returned by HTTP in most cases, however sometimes the data is already retrieved. Is that the appropriate time to use a Completer?

ex.

```
String _someData = "";

Future<String> getSomeData(){
  if (_someData == ""){
    return Api.getSomeData().then((String someData){
      _someData = someData;
      return _someData;
    });
  } else {
    var completer = new Completer();
    completer.complete(_someData);
    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

-edit- Also if I create a Completer, but end up not using its future or calling complete. Will that cause a mem leak? Should I call its complete method or dispose of it somehow?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `async` function instead.

```
import "dart:async";

String _someData = "";

Future<String> getSomeData() async {
  if (_someData == "") {
    _someData = await Api.getSomeData();
  }

  return _someData;
}
```

Compiler generates approximately the following code:

```
import "dart:async";

String _someData = "";

Future<String> getSomeData() {
  var $_awaiter = new Completer<String>();
  try {
    if (_someData == "") {
      Api.getSomeData().then(($) {
        $_awaiter.complete($);
      }).catchError((e, s) {
        $_awaiter.completeError(e, s);
      });

      return $_awaiter.future;
    } else {
      $_awaiter.complete(_someData);
      return $_awaiter.future;
    }
  } catch (e, s) {
    $_awaiter.completeError(e, s);
    return $_awaiter.future;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set _someData to a Future? Also wouldn't that block until Api.getSomeData() returned its future?

Comment: @Krtko Operator `await` always `unwrap` Future. So, as result you get a `Future.result` in this case. And it does not block a call of `Api.getSomeData()`, it will chain computation in the same way as if you will use the `Future.then()`,

Comment: @Krtko It does not blocks. An operator `await` always generates a `Completer` for you. After when `Completer` intialiazed then `Completer.future` will be returned immediatelly without blocking. When `Api.getSomeData()` will be completed it completed `Completer`. Next step will be invocation of `Completer.future.whenComplete()`. So, there is no any blocking operations because all of them was perviously not blocked but scheduled by microtask or by timer by the internal implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the named constructor `Future.value` if the value is immediately accessible. You won't need a `Completer`.

```
String _someData = "";

Future<String> getSomeData(){
  if (_someData == ""){
    return Api.getSomeData().then((String someData){
      _someData = someData;
      return _someData;
    });
  } else {
    return new Future.value(_someData);
  }
}
```

And for your second question, if you create a `Completer` without using it, I guess the garbage collector will simply free its memory when there won't be anymore references to it in your code.

Comment: Disadvantage of such way in that the if you change `_somedata` from field to `getter` and if this `getter` will throw an exception then your function `getSomeData` wil not return the result (`Future`, in our case) but it will throw an exception. This means that it is an unsafe (semi-asynchronous) implementation and requires take special precautions in other code where it will be used because it does not ensures that it returns a `Future`.